# Where did Galileo say "All truths are easy to understand once they are discovered. The point is to discover them."?

Tags: reference-request, quote, galileo

I've heard it claimed Galileo said or wrote:

> All truths are easy to understand once they are discovered. The point is to discover them.

Where did he say this?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

[*Dialogo sopra i due massimi sistemi del mondo*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dialogue_Concerning_the_Two_Chief_World_Systems) (1632), Day Two:

> SAGR. Tali [facili da intendersi] sono tutte le cose vere, doppo che son trovete; ma il punto sta nel saperle trovare.
>
> [Stilmann Drake transl., p.225] So [easy to understand] are all truths, once they are discovered; the point is in being able to discover them.
>
> [ [Th.Salusbury transl.,209](http://archimedes.mpiwg-berlin.mpg.de/cgi-bin/toc/toc.cgi?step=thumb&dir=galil_syste_065_en_1661)] So are all truths, when once they are found out, but the difficulty lyeth in finding them.

Comment: ha ha this is false :D there are so high and difficult mathematics nobody can understand only 100 or less person, i.e FERMAT THEOREM proof by andrew wiles

Comment: @JoseJavierGarcia - The question is: "Where (if any) Galileo writes... ?" and **not** "Is Galileo right in writing ... ?".